# Image Path not resolving properly React while using resolve(path)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

Need your help.

I am trying to display an image in our application and I am using require(path) as below.

```
const logo = require('../../public/images/logo.png');
```

in my img src..I am using as

```
<img src="::logo"/> is a different syntax we are using in our application in our internal framework.
```

this is working fine in my local and image is loading properly. But when I deploy it in the server, the path is not resolving properly. As I deploy it in our application, all the images goes to 'images' folder under 'dist'. Our applicatioURL goes similar to like this -

https://abc/def/index.html

But the image is pointing something like this ->
https://abc/def**logo.ping**

After **def**, the backslash is missing.  Ideally it should be
https://abc/def/**logo.ping**

I am assuming that some configuration is missing in our application. Can anyone throw some light here.

Comment: Try using just `'./public/images/logo.png'`.

Comment: logo.png is under public/images folder. public is folder is not the same level, hence I used ../ to navigate to parent directory.